# php md5 encrypt the post name and value?

Tags: php, post, encryption, md5

I was wondering is there a way to do this correctly?

```
<?php
$r = rand(1,10);
form -> go to this page go.php.

<input type='hidden' name='<? md5('$r') ?>' value='<? md5('..') ?>'>
?>
```

the processor page

```
<?php
switch(md5($_POST[md5(whatever $r was)])){
....
....
...
}
?>
```

Comment: Why would you like to do this?

Comment: Yeah - if this is an attempt at security, it's a very insecure one. You would have to use another way in that case

Comment: why not just pass the int, and check its an int? boggling

Comment: @Pekka why is this bad for security.... its coming  from a ajax post....

Comment: @Youngnate why are you using MD5 in the first  place? Why are you not using a simple number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're code is fine except on the PHP side. Your incoming POST variable is already md5'd. It should be:

```
Foreach ( $_POST as $_key => $_value)  {
  Switch( $_key)  {
    Case md5('..'):
      // do stuff
      Break:
   }
}
```